# getting http.client.BadStatusLine with urlopen(IP).read()

Tags: python, urllib, strip, python-3.3, urlopen

The data I am trying to read is in xml format. There is a single space before the xml declaration. I can not edit this part as it is hard coded into the data source. I can only read from it. When the url is entered in IE the data comes up. When entered in Chrome/Firefox, an error is shown but data can be viewed from view source.

Is there a way with python to either strip this space off or ignore it as IE seems to do?

(tried to add `strip()` in many places)

Or is there a way to default to the page source (I think urlopen does this already)?

Here is the line giving the error:

```
html = urlopen(address).read()
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\212311674\Desktop\Python Work\M10url.py", line 27, in <module>
  html = urlopen(address).read()
File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 160, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 473, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 491, in _open
  '_open', req)
File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 451, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1272, in http_open
  return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1257, in do_open
  r = h.getresponse()
File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 1131, in getresponse
  response.begin()
File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 354, in begin
  version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 336, in _read_status
  raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine:  <?xml version="1.0"?><controller_history_cnd>
```